# Selecting data from few relational tables based on few conditions in Django

Tags: python, django, django-select-related, django-related-manager

I'm using Django 1.6 with Python 2.7 and I have few related models:

```
# keys/models.py
class Key(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    is_valid = models.BooleanField()

# entities/models.py
class Entity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    key = models.ForeignKey('keys.Key')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# profile/models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    profile_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Is it possible to make a single-line query which would check these conditions:

- `Key.is_valid` must be `True`
- `Entity.active` must be `True`
- `Profile.profile_id` must not be `null` (or `None`)

The only thing I can pass to that query is `request.user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are wanting to get Entity objects:

```
objects = Entity.objects.filter(active=True, 
                                key__is_valid=True, 
                                user__profile__profile_id__isnull=False)
```

Comment: You are sure that this last line will work ? Enitity is not connected with Profile, it's connected with auth.User

Comment: @Silwestpl, I believe so, enitity may not be connected to profile but user is hence the double join

Comment: Yeah, `Entity` is not connected to `Profile`, but I was just testing this, seems like it works fine... Give me few more minutes to test few more cases and I'll probably accept this since it was the first answer :)

Comment: without testing it is *should* work :), the orm can follow multi relations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying to follow that way but obviously had some error somewhere... Ok, I did test it as much as possible and the query returns empty QuerySet if any of conditions is not satisfied which is pretty much what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you need:

Check entity:

```
entity = Entity.objects.filter(active=True, key__is_valid=True, user=request.user)
```

Check Profile

```
profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user, profile_id__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Will upvote this answer for effort ;) Accepted JamesO answer just because he was faster and did it in one line :) Thanks anyways!